# Vim & Java: add java import statements automatically

Tags: java, vim, import

[The tip.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_Java_import_statements_automatically) The errors are "E349: No identifier unders cursor", "E433: No tags file" and "E426: tag not found: public". I feel them unrelated or I cannot understand their message. I have the code in "~/.vimrc" and pressed "F1", "F9" and "ESC". A [related tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Type_and_run_templates_instead_of_routine_code) but more advanced. so how can I add Java import statements automatically in Vim?

**[Added]** I use Eclipse on the side but when it is down-or-slow-or-compiling-or-doning-something-stupid I use Vim. So stop here. What are the errs for?

Comment: Sorry, I know you've been told to move to eclipse 100 times and you have many really good reasons to stick with VI, but just go ahead and install Eclipse.  Use it in parallel if you must, but you just cannot beat the built-in support. No amount of typing speed increases are going to change your coding speed as much as catching a single compile error as you type it, auto-importing simply by using ctrl-space completion is just a bonus.

Comment: @Bill K Vim (not vi) can notice compile errors with plugins like syntastic http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736 It detects the errors only during file open/save, which is a deliberate design decision but it probably could be altered to show the errors while typing. I also like to check for errors only after a save since the constant visual cues tend to be annoying. By the way, vim doesn't really increase typing speed but mainly the modifying speed and the rapidness of moving around the code. The only thing that makes me sometimes use IDE are the refactoring tools.

Comment: @Naski: you are right, I was not honest how I use Vim -- most of the time and similarly to you.

Comment: @BillK.

On smaller light weight projects, I prefer VIM.  In those projects I know the API's because I designed them, and they don't rely on a lot of external API's so code completion isn't that much of a concern.  In that case, vim is way faster and easier to use.  Not just because of my typing speed, but because ever command is at my finger tips.

On larger projects, I actually prefer [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) over Eclipse.

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if VIM could do the important stuff.  Ctrl-space is about the most important feature of Eclipse.  It does code completion (allowing you to choose from suggestions where ambiguous or expanding something like IOE<ctrl-sp> to IllegalOperatorException) as well as automatic imports.  It also has "Custom versions" for Spring and many vertical apps.  You simply do yourself a disservice by not being as familiar as possible with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cursor needs to be over an identifier**

It seems like the tip requires you to position the cursor over a class name for which it will then insert the import statement. "No identifier under cursor"-error shows up when the mapping tries to use the <kbd><C-W>}</kbd> command when there is no word under the cursor.

**ctags**

The other errors show up because it also uses the command <kbd><C-W>}</kbd> which requires you to have a ctags file containing the tags for the project.  That can be generated with a ctags utility. Exuberant ctags is quite nice for that purpose:

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

Here is some information about using ctags for java (although on my system I don't have a command exuberant-ctags, it's just ctags):

http://blog.vinceliu.com/2007/08/vim-tips-for-java-2-using-exuberant.html

**Tip quality**

It looks like the mapping in that tip clobbers the default register, search register and changes the last change command, the jump stack, the tag stack and moves the cursor. So it's a quick'n dirty tip, not very elegant.

Comment: What are the tags? wget-mirrored-java-api, ctags created on it, type "String", pressing "^]" but it cannot find the tag for String. Would have been cool to browse java-api directly from Vim

Comment: @HH: You need the source code for your version of java. It might be packaged with your JDK in a file called src.zip or you may be able to download the source somewhere. You can then unzip the code somewhere and use the tags file generated from that.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to give [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) a try, which provides a very nice integration of Eclipse features into Vim. In their own words:

> "[Eclim] provides an Eclipse plug-in
>   that exposes Eclipse features through
>   a server interface, and a set of Vim
>   plug-ins that communicate with Eclipse
>   over that interface."

Comment: Eclim's surprisingly easy to setup and you just run `:JavaImportMissing` from vim to add those imports.

Answer (score 1):

I am a dyed in the wool VI programmer, but I know to use the right tools for the right job.  If you want automatic inclusion of import statements while you're coding, just use an IDE already.  Eclipse is great; you can even shell out to VIM sometimes if you need to.