# Generate imports list for Java File

Tags: java, vim

I'm writing some Java code in vim and *really* miss the feature afforded by the IDEs such that I can type up a block of code, and after a few keystrokes have the IDE infer which imports it should place at the top of my file based on the classes I've used in my code.

Anyone know of a way to achieve this functionality in vim?  I'm thinking a command-line tool I can shell to for the file being edited. The tool would ideally dump the imports to the screen after it's analysed my Java file.

Comment: possible solution? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_Java_import_statements_automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these links

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add_Java_import_statements_automatically

[Vim & Java: add java import statements automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748232/vim-java-add-java-import-statements-automatically)

Haven't tried it myself but its a good start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to boil down to two different approaches, ones like Amir suggested where some process generates a mapping file from classes on the file system, or the approach I ended up taking where the plugin communicates real-time to a process that does the heavy lifting (Eclipse).

So I chose [Eclim](http://eclim.org/), seems antithetical to vim's light weight mantra, but in the end was the best featured approach.